# JSON Deserialize - Conversion Issue

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft JSON Serialization(packages\Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.2\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll) to convert the string to Class Domain in C#. but when i created a domain with Get / Set property. It is not converted.

```
 public class Account
{
    private string _Email = string.Empty;
    private bool _Active = false;
    private DateTime _CreatedDate = new DateTime();
    private IList<string> _Roles = new List<string> ();

    public string Email { get => _Email; set => value = _Email; }
    public bool Active { get => _Active; set => value = _Active; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get => _CreatedDate; set => value = _CreatedDate; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get => _Roles; set => value = _Roles; }
}
```

Running code,

```
 string json = @"{
          'Email': 'james@example.com',
          'Active': true,
          'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
          'Roles': [
            'User',
            'Admin'
          ]
        }";

        Account account1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
        });
```

Result:

[image]

The list(roles) is converted from string. but, remaining columns, it is not converted. Screen added FYR:

Comment: As an aside, is there any reason you're not using automatically implemented properties? Your code could be a lot simpler if you used them. (And you'd have avoided this problem entirely.)

Comment: If you Paste JSON as Classes in VS it will create the class for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not getting converted because you are assigning the `value` with your backing field, while it should be upside down.

You are currently doing this

```
public string Email { get => _Email; set => value = _Email }
```

This is incorrect, if you really want to use backing fields, then do it like

```
public string Email { get => _email; set => _email = value; }
```

(also note, that I changed the backing field to Camel Cased, which is more up to date with [coding conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions) in C#)

The reason that it works with a list, is that NewtonSoft sees a list, and simply adds the items to your list (it only does a get, but no set)

In fact, you don't need any of the backing fields, you can just solve it through auto properties

```
public class Account
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get; } = new List<string>();
}
```